# apt-get install -—allow-unauthenticated is not understood in combination with the other options

Tags: apt

I am trying to install a local pacakge that I created, but evevrytime I run the command

```
sudo apt-get install -—allow-unauthenticated my-pack.deb
```

I get the following error:

> E: Command line option '?' [from -—allow-unauthenticated] is not understood in combination with the other options.

can someone help me fix it?

Comment: Did you copy-paste that command from a website? it looks like `-—allow-unauthenticated` contains a unicode [em dash](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2014/index.htm) in place of a regular ASCII dash

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks for your input. I was copying and pasting form a text editor. and hence was facing the issue.